# Copying worksheets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a shared Excel workbook with two worksheets in it named "PREVIOUS" and "CURRENT".  At the end of the night, I would like to click a button or perform some action to have the CURRENT sheet copy the information it contains to the PREVIOUS sheet with the same formatting, spacing etc.  I would also like the CURRENT sheet to blank out several cells.  The data deleted in those cells is always in the same location.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "shared" workbook, does that mean that many people can edit the workbook at the same time? If so, don't bother putting more work into the workbook, because it is a lost cause. It is just a matter of time until the workbook will become corrupt, show inexplicable behaviour and become a pain to work with.

Other than that, I'd like to recommend a good-practice approach to put data entry in one sheet and reports in other sheets. There is no need to separate or "clean out" data entry at the end of the day. You just need to train your users to add new data at the end of the data entry sheet.

You can then create reports on that continuous data table, slicing and dicing the data into chunks according to days, months, or any other grouping criteria.